# Why no Zend_Layout helper or codebehind? And best way to

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-layout

I was just wondering why no code-behind or helpers were made to work with layouts? I have stuff I want to display in my layouts without having to set it up in a placeholder for every single controller.

I was also wanted to know what is the best way to persist a display-once "success-message" across many pages. For example, a user fills out a form and when it is submitted correctly they are redirected to another page. I want the user to see a success message on that other page. Is there some sort of provision in Zend Framework that makes this easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for the messages you can use the [Flash Messenger helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger)

As far as setting up the place holders you could use a base controller and set these up in the `init` method overriding on descendents when necessary.

Comment: +1. Other alternatives to base controller include: action helper and front-controller plugin.

Comment: Ah, so just do a "zf create controller BaseController" and then have everything extend that controller? Or is there another way of doing that that I am missing?

Comment: Well as David suggested you could use a action helper or FrontController plugin, which honestly is a better way to go if the project is pretty large. But if you want to jsut "get it done" using a base controller class is probably the easiest way. I wouldnt create it with Zend_Tool though because it really belongs in your `Library` not in your `Application`.